# Codeigniter 404 page not found

Tags: apache, codeigniter

I have been developing a Codeigniter website locally for with a WAMP server on Windows, everything working fine. I uploaded the files to a Ubuntu server to a virtual directory and configuration the URL and .htaccess. The rewrite rule works like it should but now I get 404 when I try to access the site or any other controller link. The logs state that it cannot find the controller, I checked the files to make sure they were uploaded correctly.

At this point and I at a loss, I have a hunch that it is a configuration issue with Apache but I have checked all the configs that I know. What would cause a 404 error?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

        # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
        RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
        RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

        # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Can you update the question with `.htaccess` file content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have activated the module rewrite? If not, turn it on and restart wamp.

Also try to put index.php before the controller, may resolve the problem.

Comment: Mid rewrite works. Would there be something else that would cause it to act this way.

Comment: What is the content of your .htaccess file?
Which URL you are using to access the controller?

What is the name of your php file controller? (Maybe it's a problem with case sensitive)

Comment: I just updated the questions with the contents of the .htaccess. Everything works fine when I test locally in WAMP. I have other websites running on the same Ubuntu server running just fine.

Comment: So I uploaded a fresh copy of Codeigniter and it worked. It has something to do with the case sensitive apparently. Do you know if in Codeignitor 3.0.1 they changed the way it intrepret case? I my controller was Users with a file name of users.php. I changed the file name to Users.php and it worked. But now I have an issue where CI isn't finding my models.

Comment: Apparently naming conventions did change from 2.0 to 3.0. Files must be begin with a capital on all files in controllers, models, views, libraries, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In CI 3.0, All Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. 
Example: Where Model_name is the name of your class, this is how the class should be;

class User_model extends CI_Model {

```
    public function __construct()
    {
            parent::__construct();
    }
```

}

Then, the model should be loaded like this in the controller;

$this->load->model('user_model');

Please refer to this link: http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html

Comment: Please quot the relevant parts from the link so that if the link will become unavailable the answer will still be valid.